# How to set a font family to an app when your phone use custom font family?

Tags: android, fonts

I have created an Android app with an "Arial" font family, my phone use a custom font family and when i launch my application i dont have an Arial font family but the custom font family of my phone. Any idea how to fix that?

[Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMm25.png)

[TextView code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpcYz.png)

[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xofAW.png)

[What i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEMVF.png)

Comment: share some code, manifest, layout xml, style xml

Comment: Change `android:fontFamily` to just `fontFamily`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and help us to help you - code as images is not really of help.

Comment: @Vucko I already try this, didn't work :/

Comment: @Adinia Yeah sorry i'm new i go check that !

Comment: From the bits available, you seem to have not added your desired font in the app. See [Downloadable Fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts) and [Fonts in XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml) and

Comment: @Adinia it work thx ! (unfortunatly didnt work with "sans serif" but that fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set font family in every text view using.

```
<TextView
   android:fontFamily="@font/fontfamily"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Jetpack Compose you can do it in following way:

1. Create a `FontFamily`:

`val FontFamilyArial = FontFamily(Font(R.font.arial_normal,FontWeight.Normal))`

2. Create your own `Typography`:

`val ArialTypography = Typography(defaultFontFamily = FontFamilyArial)`

3. Create your own `ComposeTheme`:

```
@Composable
fun ArialComposeTheme(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    MaterialTheme(
        typography = ArialTypography
    )
}
```

4. Wrap your `Composeable`s in your `ArialComposeTheme`:

```
@Composable
fun ComposeView() {
    MapsComposeTheme {
      Box()...
    }
}
```